# ZipOutputStream relative paths

Tags: java, path, zip, relative-path

I create zip file using ZipOutputStream. I put in the zip one file(both file and zip are in the same dir), however the file is stored with fullpath (C:\TEMP\file.xml), how to store it with relative or no path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set that in the [ZipEntry](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipEntry.html#ZipEntry%28java.lang.String%29). For example, if you don't want any path, just use the name of the file in your ZipEntry, like this:

```
    File f = new File("C:\\temp\\file.xml");
    ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(f.getName());
```

Comment: This presumes the working dir of your app is C:\\temp\ otherwise it won't find the file to put in the zip.